# Spring Boot Ajax populate a select options dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, spring

Hello every one i have the following question ,i have a select tag that i want to populate with a list objects Here some code to explain:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getAllIndustries")
@ResponseBody
public List<IndustryModel>getAllIndustries()
{
    return generalSettingMerchantLookUpService.getBusinessNature(Constant.MERCHANT);
}
```

This return a list of industries models ,the following is the java script that i am using

```js
function industryAjax()
{
 alert("i am here")
var businessNatureId= $("#industrySelect option:selected").val();
 
 $.ajax({
  url : getContextPath() + "/getAllIndustries",
  type : "get",
  success : function(response) {
   $('#industrySelect').empty();
   $('#industrySelect').append($('<option>', {
       value: 0,
       text:  'Select'
   }));
   for (item in response) {
    $('#industrySelect').append($('<option>', {
        value: response[item].industryId,
        text:  response[item].industryInEnglish
    }));
   }
  },
  error : function(e) {
   // alert("Submit failed" + JSON.stringify(e));
  }
 });
}
```

And here i my html

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
 <label>Industry</label> <select class="form-control m-b"
 id="industrySelect" name="industryId" onchange="industryChange();">
  <option value="0">Choose Industry</option></select>
<p id="chooseIndustry" style="color: red;">please choose a valid industry</p>
</div>
```

So how can i display the list of industries that i get from controller in the html ,Best Regards

Comment: And what is the problem with code above? Looks fine

Comment: unfortunately no data is retrieved when i click on the drop down list

Comment: i change it to become on click now it gets the data the problem is when i add an industry and then retrieve the industries list the latest added industry is not there i don't understand why ,any help would be appreciated .

Comment: Debug the JS code and check whether all the industries there. if not check server side.

Comment: thanks man i solve the issue by changing the event to on mouse enter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be the case that this method is not getting invoked because initially your dropdown does not contain any element. So there will not be any `onchange` event fired.

Try using below implementation:

```
$(document).on('click', "#industrySelect", function(event) {
    industryAjax();
});
```

Comment: thank you,i solved the problem by doing this onmouseenter="industryChange();

Comment: `onmouseenter` event will not work if you are not using mouse. The above implementation would work with mouse as well as keyboard.